# When using SinonJS in Typescript private properties are reported as missing

Tags: typescript, sinon, stub

I'm trying to stub a class instance using `sinon.createStubInstance` but I'm getting an error stating that a private member variable is missing. Of course I can't explicitly set it either because it's a private member.

Example classes:

```
class Foo {
  private readonly bar: string;

  constructor(bar: string) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

class Parent {
  foos: Foo[];

  constructor(foos: Foo[]) {
    this.foos = foos;
  }
}
```

And in the test I'm writing a `beforeEach` block:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  const stubFoo = sinon.createStubInstance(Foo);

  const stubParent = sinon.createStubInstance(Parent);
  stubParent.foos = [stubFoo]; // Tslint error here
});
```

The Tslint error is:

> Property 'bar' is missing in type 'SinonStubbedInstance' but
>   required in type 'Foo'

For the record I'm using Typescript v3.0.3 and Sinon v7.4.1.

Comment: Works quite well in [a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4yy5yr). Your version of TypeScript is quite old (we are currently at 3.6.3), so I would advise to update it.

Comment: @frankie567 That's missing the key line on the bottom `stubParent.foos = [stubFoo];`. Thanks for the heads up about the TypeScript version.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I've missed that. Problem here is that `stubFoo` is of type `SinonStubbedInstance<Foo>`, which is not a sub-type of `Foo`, thus, not assignable. What you could do is to cast it `stubParent.foos = [<Foo>stubFoo]` ; not very elegant but, well, test setups can be cumbersomes.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case it requires `stubParent.foos = [<Foo><unknown>stubFoo]` because without the initial cast to `<unknown>` it still complains that the private property is not defined. If I make the member public though things just work, `SinonStubbedInstance<Foo>` is a valid sub-type of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [this solution](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1963#issuecomment-888247767) found by a Github user (paulius-valiunas):

> if you just want to use this in a couple places, a simpler and more readable solution would be to use the type alias `StubbedClass<T> = SinonStubbedInstance<T> & T` directly. For example:
>
> ```
> export type StubbedClass<T> = SinonStubbedInstance<T> & T;
> const myStub = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass) as StubbedClass<MyClass>;
> ```
>
> or just:
>
> ```
> const myStub = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass) as SinonStubbedInstance<MyClass> & MyClass;
> ```

way cleaner and simpler than other suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a nicer workaround than force-casting your stub, [posted on github here](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1963#issuecomment-497349920):

```js
import { createStubInstance, StubbableType, SinonStubbedInstance, SinonStubbedMember } from 'sinon';

export type StubbedClass<T> = SinonStubbedInstance<T> & T;

export function createSinonStubInstance<T>(
  constructor: StubbableType<T>,
  overrides?: { [K in keyof T]?: SinonStubbedMember<T[K]> },
): StubbedClass<T> {
  const stub = createStubInstance<T>(constructor, overrides);
  return stub as unknown as StubbedClass<T>;
}
```

You can then use it as such:

```js
beforeEach(function () {
  const stubFoo: StubbedClass<Foo> = createSinonStubInstance(Foo);
  const stubParent: StubbedClass<Parent> = createSinonStubInstance(Parent);

  stubParent.foos = [stubFoo]; // No more Tslint error here
});
```

It worked for me on a different configuration, and bring all the autocompletion for both my classes and Sinon's stubbed instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for a quick work around:

```
stubParent.foos = [stubFoo as unknown as Foo];
```

I still haven't found any elegant way to solve this as of the moment of writing this.